# When clicked button Next

Tags: java, android, arrays

Could you please explain me this :

```
 mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
```

QuestionBank is an array with some datas.

I understand first part which means increasing currentIndex, but what is next %Questionbank.length??

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is a remainder/modulo division operator - gives you the remainder

Comment: ok currentIndex=0  and  aray.length equal to 5    and then after  above code mCurrentIndex will be equal to ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mCurrentIndex` may be some `indexnumber` of array adding `1` make the element number like if `mCurrentIndex = 1` then `(mCurrentIndex+1)` make it 2 then `%` means module operatore also remainder operator.
it module with length of array to restrict equation that after increment value can't be exceed to length.

Comment: ok currentIndex=0 and aray.length equal to 5 and then after above code mCurrentIndex will be equal to 2??

Comment: ok, I got it, so (1+1)%5 will return 2,   (2+1)%5=3     thank you                          and what about this formula:   x%y=>x - (r*y) = z    x/y=r,s       e.g.    3%5     and  3/5=0,6  then  z= 3-(0*5)=3    lol

Answer (score 2):

That's modulus.  Basically it divides by the length, and takes the remainder of the result.  This code will basically increment `mCurrentIndex`, and wrap it around to `0` if it gets too big for the `array`.

Answer (score 0):

It's too make sure it does not overflow.
If the array was the length 10, and you tried to use index 10, it would instead change it to 0